# Counting with maximum restriction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Need help approaching this question but really lost. There are $20$ fruits, $5$ apples, $5$ oranges $5$ bananas and $5$ pears. How many ways can we choose $10$ fruits. Ive tried the stars and bars, but i dont know how to calculate for when a fruit is chosen more than $5$ times, any ideas?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion based on whether or not any of the upper bound conditions are violated.  This example has the convenient nature that you cannot have simultaneously taken too many of more than one type of fruit at a time.  Count how many ways if you ignore the number of each type of fruit there is.  Then subtract the number of ways where you had too many apples, subtract the number of ways where you had too many oranges, etc... (*add back the number of ways you had too many of two fruits simultaneously, subtracting again having too many of three fruits etc... for the generalized problem*)

Answer (score 0):

A point to note is that you can't have more than five of two different fruits.  Using stars and bars, compute the number of ways to choose ten fruits with no restriction.  Then compute the number of ways to choose ten fruits that include exactly $6,7,8,9,10$ apples, leaving $4,3,2,1,0$ others.  Subtract four times the sum of those because any fruit could be the one with more than $5$.  You don't need inclusion-exclusion because of the first sentence.